# What Do We Envision the Fabric of Space to Be? Physical or Immaterial?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, spacetime, vacuum

Sorry if this question is a bit lackluster or based on mistaken proof, I’m a high school student who’s highly interested in the fields of Quantum Theory and particle physics, and I’m trying to get a grasp on the concept of the fundamental.

What do we envision the fabric of space to be?
Is it a specific, manipulatable, and tangible ‘object’ that contains all other objects within it? Or is it a manifestation of the latent energy of the quantum vacuum state within the system that is the universe? Maybe I’m misguided on the idea of energy and mass equivalence, but it seems that either

1. the structure that holds matter and energy within itself [the universe] is incapable of possessing a mass or energy itself, and the constituent fabric that weaves the structure of the universe also does not have energy and is not matter.
2. The fabric of space exists with energy and as matter, and must exist in the lowest possible energy state and as the smallest and weakest possible mass.

If the constituent fabric of the universe is incapable of possessing an energy or mass, then it must be impossible for energy or mass to
form from that which does not possess either (notwithstanding any unknown or hidden processes in which mass or energy can magically be created in a system in which there is no matter and energy)

Therefore, we get to the root of my question; is it possible to consider the fabric of space as a manifestation of the latent energy of any specific region of space? In other words, if everything else [matter] is overlayed onto the most fundamental masses and energy states, and is incapable of possessing mass and energy values smaller than the fundamental values, would the object/entity that possesses those fundamental values be considered the fabric of space?

Comment: Depends on your theory.  The "fabric" (horrible description!) of _relativity_ is called the metric (basically a mathematical grid for measuring things) and has no physical embodiment whatsoever.  I'll let others put the _quantum_ viewpoint.

Comment: The fabric of space is a very popular but inaccurate way to describe spacetime in a way that makes the idea of curvature understandable. It leads to many misunderstandings about general relativity. Here is a video that improves on the idea. [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc)

Comment: *What do we envision the fabric of space to be?* It’s just a poor metaphor for pseudo-Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Best not to mix physical/material and immaterial with tangible and intangible. They aren't replacements for each other.

Comment: *Is it possible to consider the fabric of space as a manifestation of the latent energy of any specific region of space?* General Relativity does not require any concept of vacuum energy due to, say, quantum fluctuations.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever spacetime is, we have to grant that it has the capacity to support propagation of gravitational waves.

The LIGO observatory registers the passage of gravitational waves. The frequency range that LIGO is sensitive in is the range of gravitational waves emitted in the following three categories of merging event:

- Neutron star - neutron star merger
- Black hole - neutron star merger
- Black hole - Black hole merger

There is a note by Kirk T. McDonald, Princeton university, discussing the Young modulus of elasticity of spacetime. The title of the note is: [What is the stiffness of spacetime?](http://kirkmcd.princeton.edu/examples/stiffness.pdf)

McDonald arrives at a number for Young's modulus of elasticity, of spacetime, that is in the order of $10^{20}$ times larger than that of steel.

McDonald mentions that his note was triggered by the response by Kip Thorne (during the question time after a lecture) to an audience question about the modulus of elasticity of spacetime. This response is at 1:21:20 of the [Kip Thorne Lecture](http://www.kaltura.com/tiny/r63ta)

Upon being asked about the modulus of elasticity of spacetime Kip Thorne looks up to the audience and says: "Ray, help me.". [Rainer Weiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainer_Weiss) then proceeds to give the order of magnitude indication of $10^{20}$ higher than the modulus of elasticity of steel.

Of course: this attribution of a modulus of elasticity is by analogy. In a solid the propagation speed of a disturbance is proportional to the stiffness of the material.

For spacetime: in terms of GR: the default state is to be geometrically flat. Presence of gravitational mass induces curvature. There is a strong tendency to return to the geometrically flat state. The modulus of elasticity is a measure of how strong that tendency is.

On the other hand: while matter has parts that can be tracked through time, spacetime hasn't.

Curvature of spacetime is a quantifiable concept, but it cannot be observed directly. Its existence is inferred from observations; the concept of curvature of spacetime allows us to account for observed gravitational interaction of celestial bodies.

These concepts must be granted in order to be able to formulate a theory at all.

Envisioning what spacetime is can be pushed only so far. My preference is to be cautious and just grant what is necessary. It seems to me: it's probably better to try and hold back on interpretation, for the purpose of avoiding over-interpretation.

Further reading:
Andrew J. S. Hamilton, Jason P. Lisle: [the river model of black holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060)